# How to make the listview align better?

Tags: qt, qml

My program consisted of a tabbar and stackLayout. I face a layout problem that the tab button is too close to the head of the listview as shown below. They are horizontally aligned together.

But I want the listview to be under the tab button. I tried adding the topMargin in the listview, but it doesn't have any effect at all. Please help.

[image]

The code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.8
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import com.contentplayermod.filemodel 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")
    property int idx: 0
    property bool isActive: true

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Main")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("View")            
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: stackLayout
        height:parent.height
        width: parent.width
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        Item  {
            id: mainTab
            anchors {
                topMargin:60
            }
            width: 500
            height:800

            ListView {
                id: lv                
                anchors.margins: 50
                width: 200; height: 400
                highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
                focus: true
                currentIndex: 0

                Component {
                    id: fileDelegate

                    Text {

                        text: fileName
                        font.pointSize: 20
                        anchors {
                            topMargin:60
                        }
                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: parent                            
                        }
                    }

                }

                model: FileModel{

                    id: myModel
                    folder: "c:\\folder"
                    nameFilters: ["*.mp4","*.jpg"]
                }

                delegate: fileDelegate
                highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true

            }            
        }

        Item  {
            id: viewTab
            width: 500
            height:800           

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The native [`TabView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html) does not fit your needs ?

Comment: It is not QtQuick.Controls 2.0 above. I cannot use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either `anchors` your stack-top to the bottom of the tab bar like this :

```
...
StackLayout {
    id: stackLayout
    height:parent.height - bar.height
    anchors.top: bar.bottom
    width: parent.width
    ...
```

Or much simpler, put everything in a `ColumnLayout` :

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        ...
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: stackLayout
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        ...
    }
}
```

So you don't have to deal with width and height, and it's more easy to insert new widgets in your window.

You can add `spacing` to the `ColumnLayout` to put some space between the TabBar and the content. Or manage this inside the `Item`s displayed by the `StackLayout` for more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The first method suits me.